# how to repeat word specific times in python?

Tags: python

by using 2 lists

```
word = [wood, key, apple, tree]
times = [2,1,3,4]
```

I want to make as a below result.

```
result = [wood, wood, key, apple, apple, apple, tree, tree, tree, tree]
```

i tried `word * times` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of it procedurally instead of some math/magical operation. In other words, what sequence of steps will give me the desired result. There may be ways to condense but need to understand logic to achieve.

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(words)):
    for t in range(0, times[i]):
            result.append(words[i])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
word = ['wood', 'key', 'apple', 'tree']
times = [2,1,3,4]
result = [a for a, b in zip(word, times) for _ in range(b)]
```

Output:

```
['wood', 'wood', 'key', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'tree', 'tree', 'tree', 'tree']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
word = ["wood", "key", "apple", "tree"]
times = [2,1,3,4]

print(np.repeat(word, times))
```

['wood' 'wood' 'key' 'apple' 'apple' 'apple' 'tree' 'tree' 'tree' 'tree']

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate and loop through the word list.

```
word = ["wood", "key", "apple", "tree"]
times = [2,1,3,4]
results = []

for i,w in enumerate(word):
    for _ in range(times[i]):
            results.append(w)

print(results)

# ['wood', 'wood', 'key', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'tree', 'tree', 'tree', 'tree']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools it can be done as below:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
word = ['wood', 'key', 'apple', 'tree']
times = [2,1,3,4]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, word, times)))
print(result)
```

Using collections it can be done as below:

```
from collections import Counter
word = ['wood', 'key', 'apple', 'tree']
times = [2,1,3,4]
result = list(Counter(dict(zip(word,times))).elements())
print(result)
```